# vertical alignment doesn't work

Tags: html, css

So here's what's going on

[image]

I wanted to vertical align that arrow on the right to be at the center of the div. Here's the html:

```
<div class="title-block" >
    <span class="date">{{ order.getCreated()|date('M d, Y') }}</span>
    <span class="invoice">Invoice #{{ order.getInvoice().getInvoiceNumber()}}</span>
    <span class="retail-price">Rp {{ order.getTotalPrice() }}</span>
    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/shopiousmain/img/dashboard-li-down-arrow.png') }}"/>
</div>
```

As you can see on the image below:

[image]

It's vertical align is already set to middle. However, why is it not vertically centered?

Comment: remove float:right than used to vertical-align:middle

Comment: Can you try `.title-block > * { vertical-align: middle; }` once?

Comment: @RohitAzad but I wanted the img to be on the right..

Comment: @Ronak where do I put that?

Comment: Vertical-align only works on inline* or table-cell elements.  Floating an element changes its display type to be neither of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `float:right` will fix it but then you'll lose the float.
Alternatively, if you know the element's height and you are sure it wont change, you could try this:

```
.title-block img {
  position:absolute;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Now used to this** Define your `.title-block` `position relative;` and your `img tag` `absolute` and define `right:0; top:xxx;` **according to your design** ..

```
.title-block{position:relative;}
#order-history .data-container-body .data-block .title-block img{
float:none;
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:10px; // according to your design set 
}
```

Comment: this is hard coding it, is there no way to just vertical-align it so that when I change the div height it is automatically centered

Comment: ...I don't understand, I basically want to eliminate using that top: x px by using vertical-align